# RGB LED and which drivers

Tags: led, rgb

I previously asked [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86652/2028) regarding 50W RGB multi chips and 50W warm white drivers. Here is [the driver](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/310775786619?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649), a 50W RGB chip draws much lower amperage and compatible drivers usually max out at 650 milliamperes.

Most of my question was kindly answered in last post, but with the above driver, could I run my 50W RGB chip? Would devices such as "buck" and "step down" enable me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The specification of that item is not sufficient to answer your question.
To drive LEDs (or any load,) you need to supply the right voltage with the capability of delivering the right amperage.
If your amperage capability is too weak, you will burn out your supply, and/or not get up to the appropriate voltage.
Given a wattage, you can calculate the amperage, if you have the voltage, or vice versa, using Ohm's law. Just be sure to not confuse DC volts/amps with RMS volts/amps, or "watts" with "VA" for AC equiment.

If a power supply has too much amperage for a given load, then that's typically fine; you will just have some margin and the power supply will run cooler than designed, which will generally improve lifetime.

For your RGB LEDs, we need to know the voltage they expect to be driven at, to be able to tell you whether the power supply you point at will work. We also need to know the voltage of that power supply (although that may be calculable from the given specifications of 50W and 1700 mA -- which would indicate just under 30 Volts ?)

Comment: Hello the 50w RGB chip requires 350MA, dc forward voltage is red 16-20, green 24-28, blue 24-28. My 50w driver is for white LED and commands 1.5A, can I use both together?! Or is there a device such as buck or step down to help me do this.